# Dynamic imports in Cypress tests using Typescript: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cypress, ts-loader

I'm trying to use dynamic imports in my cypress tests, like this const `inputModule = await import('../../__tests__/testCases/baseInput');`

But I'm getting this error:
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 1 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/__cypress/iframes/integration/1.cases.spec.ts)

This is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = on => {
  const options = {
    webpackOptions: {
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: { transpileOnly: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };
  on('file:preprocessor', wp(options));
};
```

And this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["cypress/**/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.js"],
  "exclude": [],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to add this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
  }
```

and this to my webpack config

```
output: {
        fileName: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFileName: '[name].bundle.js',
      }
```